# how to change xterm font?

Tags: arch-linux, i3, xterm

I created a .Xresources file and added the following code to it(I’m demonstrating only a part, because there’s a lot of code):

```
XTerm*font:*-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-koi8-r 
XTerm*eightBitInput: false
XTerm*utf8: 1
XTerm*locale: 1

! Fonts ====================================================
! set font and fontsize
XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 16

! VT Font Menu: Unreadable
xterm*faceSize1: 8
! VT font menu: Tiny
xterm*faceSize2: 10
! VT font menu: Medium
xterm*faceSize3: 12
! VT font menu: Large
xterm*faceSize4: 16
! VT font menu: Huge
xterm*faceSize5: 22


! Ensure that your locale is set up for UTF-8. If you do not use UTF-8, you may need to force xterm to more strictly follow your locale by setting
XTerm.vt100.locale: true
...
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl <Key> minus: smaller-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key> plus: larger-vt-font() \n\
    Ctrl <Key> 0: set-vt-font(d) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Shift <Btn1Up>: exec-formatted("xdg-open '%t'", PRIMARY) \n\
    <Btn1Up>: select-end(PRIMARY, CLIPBOARD, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
    <Btn2Up>: insert-selection(PRIMARY)
...
*background: #002b36
*foreground: #657b83
!!*fading: 40
*fadeColor: #002b36
*cursorColor: #93a1a1
*pointerColorBackground: #586e75
*pointerColorForeground: #93a1a1
...
```

I copied this text from a video on YouTube, so I don’t understand its meaning well. After which I added the following lines to .xinitrc:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xresources ]] && xrdb -merge -I$HOME ~/.Xresources
exec i3
```

xterm changes the background color, as specified in .Xresources, but the font does not change and the hotkeys do not work. I tried to change the font size using ctrl+rmouse, but when I select any of the options, nothing changes.However, when I launch xterm using

> xterm -fn *-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-koi8-r

the font changes. what am I doing wrong?

- I use arch with xorg, xterm, i3wm

Comment: running xrdb won't change a currently running xterm (colors are a special case, because the VT100 widget has a callback for that, which potentially can be invoked - though rarely done).

Comment: @Thomas Dickey 1. I call xrdb in .xinitrc, as recommended on   https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_resources_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) 2. when opening a new terminal, the font does not change, although the xrdb -query -all command shows that all settings in the configuration file are loaded

Answer (score 1):

In the example, xterm is using TrueType fonts.  xterm has a (little-used) widget method for setting values at runtime in the VT100 widget, but that does not cover TrueType fonts.

See [**`VTSetValues`**](https://github.com/ThomasDickey/xterm-snapshots/blob/d78ea209be32bcbcebcb91bb2037a9c59af61c9b/charproc.c#L12536) in source code:

```c
    if (xtermLoadFont(newvt,
              xtermFontName(TScreenOf(newvt)->MenuFontName(TScreenOf(curvt)->menu_font_number)),
              True, TScreenOf(newvt)->menu_font_number)) {
        /* resizing does the redisplay, so don't ask for it here */
        refresh_needed = True;
        fonts_redone = True;
    } else if (strcmp(NonNull(DefaultFontN(curvt)), NonNull(DefaultFontN(newvt)))) {
        TScreenOf(newvt)->MenuFontName(fontMenu_default) = DefaultFontN(curvt);
    }
```

If that does not work for bitmap fonts (XLFD), then

- a bug report is due, or if the TrueType font is used as shown, then
- a feature request may be considered.

(StackExchange isn't the proper place to discuss either).

This fragment

```
XTerm*font:*-terminus-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-koi8-r 
XTerm*eightBitInput: false
XTerm*utf8: 1
XTerm*locale: 1

! Fonts ====================================================
! set font and fontsize
XTerm*faceName: DejaVu Sans Mono
XTerm*faceSize: 16
```

appears to say that you added the lines before "Fonts ===".
However, the [`faceName`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:faceName) resource overrides the [`font`](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:font) resource, as noted in the manpage:

> If no **`faceName`** resource is specified, or if there is no match
> for both *TrueType* normal and bold fonts, xterm uses the *XLFD*
> (bitmap) font and related resources.

Removing the line with "faceName" will eliminate that conflict.

Alternatively, you can add a line to set the [**`renderFont`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:renderFont) resource, e.g.,

```
*renderFont: false
```